# Azure AD Connect Cloud password issue

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have setup Azure AD Connect Cloud. The new product from MS Azure and I am getting green lights across the board that the system is functioning properly. But on-prem password is not working

1. Cloud Sync for my domain has a Healthy Status
2. [image]
3. When creating a User or syncing an already existing user from my Test OU. They show up in AzureAD
4. I am able to add license to either user.
5. I have port 80, 443, 8080 all open for outbound connections from my server
6. I have open inbound traffic from the firewall for both *.msappproxy.net and *.servicebus.windows.net from any port to port 443 and 80 to the server

When I try to log into https://myapps.microsoft.com as described in the [MS Artical](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/cloud-sync/tutorial-single-forest). I receive the following error. "Your account or password is incorrect. If you don't remember your password. reset it now"

Has anyone see this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue with Azure AD connect cloud not syncing password hash. The issue was the admin account I was using did not have the proper rights to the domain. Once changed I was able to sync hash with no issue.

Steps to resolve this issue.
Open Active Directory Users and Computers
Right Click on the root of your domain Testsystem.local
Click on Properties
Click on Security Tab
Add in the Username you used during installation for "Azure AD Connect Cloud" for local authentication"
Under Permisssions Check "Allow" for Replicating Directory Changes & Replicating Directory Changes All

After that your system should allow Password Hash to sync. (or it did for me atleast)

Answer (score 0):

This was helped to me

net stop 'Microsoft Azure AD Sync'

net start 'Microsoft Azure AD Sync'

[More Info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/troubleshoot-sign-in#account-isnt-synchronized-into-azure-ad-ds-yet)